# How do I print Ruby objects as strings?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I have a class `Board`, which contains objects from another class `Cell` that I want to print as a board. I randomly assigned each cell a value of `'x'` or `'o'`, and I want it to print a 2d array of `'x'`'s and `'o'`'s.
Here is my code:

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :cell
  def initialize
    @cell = ['x', 'o'].sample
  end
end

class Board
  attr_reader :board
  attr_accessor :row
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(9)
    @row = Array.new(9)
    @my_cell = ''
  end
  def create_row
    self.row.map! do |empty_space|
      empty_space == nil ? Cell.new : empty_space
    end
  end
  def create_board
    self.board.map! do |empty_space|
      empty_space == nil ? self.row : empty_space
    end
  end
  def to_s
    self.board
  end
end

new_board = Board.new
new_board.create_row
new_board.create_board
puts new_board.to_s
```

When I print the board, it gives me a list of the cell object's coordinates. I can't figure it out.

Comment: For the particular customized output you'll probably want to use loops of some sort to generate a custom "pretty board". However, for fast debugging [#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) can be useful. eg: `def to_s; self.board.inspect end`

Comment: The formatting is horrible and your use of `self` is inconsistent. Sometimes you use it, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

`to_s` should return a `String`, that's why it is called `to_s` in the first place. You are returning an `Array` from `to_s`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try awesome_print. It's awesome. It dumps your objects ina very readable format eg:

```
 :014 > ap Major.first
  Major Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "majors".* FROM "majors"  ORDER BY     "majors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 #<Major:0x007f8677e77c50> {
         :id => 9,
       :name => "Art",
 :profile_id => 85676,
 :school_code => 123,
 :created_at => Fri, 11 Dec 2015 21:22:25 UTC +00:00,
 :updated_at => Fri, 11 Dec 2015 21:22:25 UTC +00:00
}
```

You can find it on github or add it to your Gemfile

```
# Installing as Ruby gem
$ gem install awesome_print

# Cloning the repository
$ git clone git://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print.git
```